# How to slice a cluster from a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

`df['clusters']` contains the data frame with 4 cluster `0,1,2,3`.
I have read the data-frame in `csv` format using `pandas` and have implemented k-means clustering and generated 4 clusters. The clusters are in `df['clusters']`.
Suppose there are 4 clusters with labels `0,1,2,3`.
Now how to slice one column and fetch the columns belonging to cluster `1`

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataframe along with your expected outcome? Then it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Arguably this is not clear from your question - you should stress that, instead of irrelevant details regarding k-means, csv etc; See updated answer below

Comment: Please edit your question rather than describing it in the comments, provide an example dataframe, show your desired outcome and the attempts you have made to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see what exactly is your issue - with `df[df['clusters'] == 3]` it works fine:

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 8, 9], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 11, 2], 'clusters':[0,2,3,3,1]})

print(df)
# result:
   a   b  clusters
0  1   3         0
1  2   4         2
2  3   5         3
3  8  11         3
4  9   2         1

print(df[df['clusters'] == 3])  
# result:
   a   b  clusters
2  3   5         3
3  8  11         3
```

Want to also drop the (now unnecessary) `clusters` column?

```
df_3 = df[df['clusters'] == 3].drop(['clusters'], axis=1) # cluster #3
print(df_3)
# result
   a   b
2  3   5
3  8  11
```

UPDATE (after comment): to slice column `a` from `df_3`:

```
df_3_a = df_3.loc[:, ['a']]
print(df_3_a)
# result:
   a
2  3
3  8
```

So, to go from the initial `df`, and selecting, say, `a` for `cluster==3`:

```
df_3_a = df[df['clusters'] == 3].drop(['clusters'], axis=1).loc[:,['a']]
print(df_3_a_)
# result:
   a
2  3
3  8
```

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut

Answer (score 0):

Not having access to your dataframe, I suggest you convert your data to a `numpy` array

```
df_array = df.to_numpy(copy=True)
```

and then:

```
df_clustered = df_array[df_array[:,cluster_data_col]==cluster_type]
```

where `cluster_data_col` is the column number where the result of your clustering is stored and `cluster_type` is the any of your four clusters.